# How much time does it take to be an English master

Tags: american-english, british-english, reported-speech, formality

How much time does it take to be an English master I mean how to speak English like your native language and how much time does it take???

Comment: This isn't answerable.  Anything from a long time to never.  Most ESL speakers never lose their accent completely.

Comment: It depends on how good you are at learning languages! It comes easily to some people and is very hard for others.

Comment: dear Îřfãň Ûłłãh Dorani. it depends on yourself. it is completely various.